# Python Pet Information (Derived Class

Tags: python, class

Hello I am struggling with figuring out how to complete this code :( I don't even know where to start! Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

The base class Pet has attributes name and age. The derived class Dog inherits attributes from the base class Pet class and includes a breed attribute. Complete the program to:

Create a generic pet, and print the pet's information using print_info().
Create a Dog pet, use print_info() to print the dog's information, and add a statement to print the dog's breed attribute.

```
Ex: If the input is:
 
Dobby 
2
Kreacher
3
German Schnauzer

the output is:
 
Pet Information:
   Name: Dobby
   Age: 2
Pet Information: 
   Name: Kreacher
   Age: 3
   Breed: German Schnauzer
```

Here's the code I have:

```
class Pet:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ''
        self.age = 0

    def print_info(self):
        print('Pet Information:')
        print('   Name:', self.name)
        print('   Age:', self.age)

class Dog(Pet):
    def __init__(self):
        Pet.__init__(self) 
        self.breed = ''

my_pet = Pet()
my_dog = Dog()

pet_name = input()
pet_age = int(input())
dog_name = input()
dog_age = int(input())
dog_breed = input()

# TODO: Create generic pet (using pet_name, pet_age) and then call print_info()

# TODO: Create dog pet (using dog_name, dog_age, dog_breed) and then call print_info()

# TODO: Use my_dog.breed to output the breed of the dog
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one of the approach:

```
class Pet:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def print_info(self):
        print('Pet Information:')
        print('   Name:', self.name)
        print('   Age:', self.age)

class Dog(Pet):
    def __init__(self, name, age, breed):
        super().__init__(name, age) 
        self.breed = breed
    def print_info(self):
        super().print_info()
        print ('   Breed:', self.breed)

pet_name = input("Pet Name:")
pet_age = int(input("Pet Age:"))
dog_name = input("Dog Name:")
dog_age = int(input("Dog Age:"))
dog_breed = input("Dog Breed:")

pet = Pet(pet_name, pet_age)
pet.print_info()
dog = Dog(dog_name, dog_age, dog_breed)
dog.print_info()
print (dog.breed)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    class Pet:
        def __init__(self, name, age):
            self.name = name
            self.age = age

        def print_info(self):
            print('Pet Information:')
            print('   Name:', self.name)
            print('   Age:', self.age)

    class Dog(Pet):
        def __init__(self, name, age, breed):
            super().__init__(name, age) 
            self.breed = breed
        def print_info(self):
            super().print_info()
            print ('   Breed:', self.breed)

    pet_name = input()
    pet_age = int(input())
    dog_name = input()
    dog_age = int(input())
    dog_breed = input()

    pet = Pet(pet_name, pet_age)
    pet.print_info()
    dog = Dog(dog_name, dog_age, dog_breed)
    dog.print_info()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
class Pet:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def print_info(self):
        print('Pet Information:')
        print('   Name:', self.name)
        print('   Age:', self.age)

class Dog(Pet):
    def __init__(self, name, age, breed):
        super().__init__(name, age) 
        self.breed = breed
    def print_info(self):
        super().print_info()
        print ('   Breed:', self.breed)

pet_name = input("Pet Name:")
pet_age = int(input("Pet Age:"))
dog_name = input("Dog Name:")
dog_age = int(input("Dog Age:"))
dog_breed = input("Dog Breed:")

my_pet.name = pet_name
my_pet.age = pet_age
my_pet.print_info()

my_dog.name = dog_name
my_dog.age = dog_age
my_dog.breed = dog_breed
my_dog.print_info()

print('   Breed:', my_dog.breed)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
class Pet:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def print_info(self):
        print('Pet Information:')
        print('   Name:', self.name)
        print('   Age:', self.age)

class Dog(Pet):
    def __init__(self, name, age, breed):
        super().__init__(name, age) 
        self.breed = breed
    def print_info(self):
        super().print_info()
        print ('   Breed:', self.breed)
        
class Dog(Pet):
    def __init__(self, name, age, breed):
        super().__init__(name, age) 
        self.breed = breed
    def print_info(self):
        super().print_info()
        print ('   Breed:', self.breed)
        
    pet_name = input()
    pet_age = int(input())
    dog_name = input()
    dog_age = int(input())
    dog_breed = input()

    pet = Pet(pet_name, pet_age)
    pet.print_info()
    dog = Dog(dog_name, dog_age, dog_breed)
    dog.print_info()

print('   Breed:', my_dog.breed)

# TODO: Create generic pet (using pet_name, pet_age) and then call print_info()
# TODO: Create dog pet (using dog_name, dog_age, dog_breed) and then call print_info()
# TODO: Use my_dog.breed to output the breed of the dog
```